# Qual o tipo de dados num Application Service com 3 tabelas distintas?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, application-service

Eu tenho um Application Service em ASP.NET Core que vai buscar a base de dados os dados de uma tabela "Employees" que são number, name, departmentname e cityname... os dois últimos campos que referi são dados de duas outras tabelas "Department" e "City". E a tabela "Employees" têm duas chaves estrangeiras para "Department" e "City".

Fiz um método

```
namespace access.track.Logicpulse {
public interface IEmployeesAppService : IApplicationService 
{
    ListResultDto<EmployeesListDto> GetEmployees(GetEmployeesInput input); }
```

que vai buscar todos employees por departmentname.

```
public ListResultDto<EmployeesListDto> GetEmployees(GetEmployeesInput input)
    {
        var emp = _employeesRepository
        .GetAll()
        .WhereIf(
            !input.Filter.IsNullOrEmpty(),
            p => p.DepartmentFk.name.Contains(input.Filter)
        )
        .OrderBy(p => p.DepartmentFk.name)
        .ToList();

        return new ListResultDto<EmployeesListDto>(ObjectMapper.Map<List<EmployeesListDto>>(emp));
    }
```

Agora o que acontece é que os campos departmentname e cityname vêm a "null" da Web API quando faço a chamada do método.

Tenho ideia que é por causa disto... mas não sei o que fazer aos campos departmentname e cityname... Qual o tipo de dados usar? (É provável que esteja a fazer a pergunta errada...)

```
namespace access.track.Logicpulse.Dtos {
public class EmployeesListDto
{
    public int number { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string departmentname { get; set; }

    public string cityname { get; set; }
}}
```

Comment: que tipo de dados o GetAll() retorna? IQueryable?

Comment: IQueryable<Employees>

Answer (score 0):

Confirme se seu modelo/classe Employees está com os relacionamentos corretos para os modelos/classes Department e City. 
Veja se esta documentação te ajuda: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx